# Openoffce Calc - Substitute space with line break by function

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

in my calc document for example cell A1 has the value

```
A1:"AB 0123"
```

and in cell B1 I need the same value with a line break instead of the space like

```
B1:"AB\n0123".
```

How can I archive this?

I tried:

```
substitute(A1;" ";"\n")
```

and the function inserted a "\n" but as string not as line break.

thx for helping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert a line break using **`CHAR(10)`**, so the following formula should work:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1; " "; CHAR(10))
```

(Tested with LibreOffice 3.6, Ubuntu)